# split text to columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, onedrive

I've this table in Excel Online (onedrive site) :

```
 PEOPLE     FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    AGE   ID
DETAILS     
DETAILS 
DETAILS
```

I would like to copy there **lines of text** and that it all will be filled into the appropriate rows.

```
for example,
Mariah Carey 30 5555
Marc Terenzi 31 7777
```

will fill the table by:

```
 PEOPLE     FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    AGE   ID
DETAILS     Mariah      Carey       30    5555
DETAILS     Marc        Terenzi     31    7777
```

Assuming that each full name contains only two names so " " (a space) can be an indicator for the new word.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `Data->Text to Columns` using space as a separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Paste the values in the column `FIRSTNAME` (Yes, data will be in one cell)
2. Select the cells with the values.
3. Go to your `Data` tab.
4. Click on `Text To Columns.`
5. Choose `Delimited` option.
6. Select `Space` as separator.
7. Click `Finish`